# Boundary sphere partial differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics

I am trying to solve partial differential equation in spherical coordinates $(\theta,\phi)$,but I don't know how to properly include boundary conditions of $\theta$. For $\phi$ it is periodic, but $\theta$ - I don't really know.

Here is my code:

```
M = 50;
z0 = 0.0;
ϕ0 = Pi;
tmax = 10;
pde = {D[Q[t, ϕ, θ], t] == -Cos[θ] D[Q[t, ϕ, θ], ϕ] + 1/M Sin[θ] D[Q[t, ϕ, θ], θ, ϕ],
       Q[t, 0, θ] == Q[t, 2 Pi, θ],
       Q[t, ϕ, 0] == Q[t, ϕ, 2 Pi],
       Q[0, ϕ, θ] == 2^-M (1 + Cos[θ] z0 + Cos[ϕ0 - ϕ] Sin[θ] Sqrt[1 - z0^2])^M};
sol = NDSolve[pde, Q, {t, 0, tmax}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}, {θ, 0, 2 Pi}];
```

$\phi \in [0,2\pi]$ and $\theta \in [0,\pi]$. Boundary condition should reflect spherical geometry.

Analytical solution (quantum mechanics derivation):

```
M = 5;
Q[t_, θ_, ϕ_] := (Sum[Binomial[M, k]*(Cos[θ/2]*Cos[θ0/2])^k*(Sin[θ/2]*Sin[θ0/2])^(M - k)*Cos[(ϕ - ϕ0)*(M - k) + t/(4*M)*(2*k - M)^2], {k, 0, M}])^2 + 
(Sum[Binomial[M, k]*(Cos[θ/2]*Cos[θ0/2])^k*(Sin[θ/2]*Sin[θ0/2])^(M - k)*Sin[(ϕ - ϕ0)*(M - k) + t/(4*M)*(2*k - M)^2], {k, 0, M}])^2;
```

with initial conditions:

```
θ0 = Pi/2;
ϕ0 = Pi;
```

You can check for yourself:

```
D[Q[t, θ, ϕ], t] + Cos[θ]*D[Q[t, θ, ϕ], ϕ] - 1/M*Sin[θ]*D[Q[t, θ, ϕ], ϕ, θ] // Simplify
```

Comment: Er… so what's your boundary condition of `θ`, in traditional math notation? BTW I think it'll be better if you mention some background information of your PDE.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The differential equation should reflect the fact that `θ` ranges between `0` and `Pi`.  Because the spherical coordinate system becomes degenerate at these two pole, `Q` should be independent of `ϕ` there.  Thus, from the differential equation, `Q` is time-independent at the poles.  Hence, the boundary values of `Q` at `0` and `Pi` are the initial values there.  Based on these considerations, the code becomes

```
pde = {D[Q[t, ϕ, θ], t] == -Cos[θ]*D[Q[t, ϕ, θ], ϕ] + 1/M*Sin[θ]*D[Q[t, ϕ, θ], θ, ϕ],
       Q[t, 0, θ] == Q[t, 2*Pi, θ],
       Q[t, ϕ, 0] == (1 + z0) 2^-M, Q[t, ϕ, Pi] == (1 - z0) 2^-M,
       Q[0, ϕ, θ] == 2^-M*(1 + Cos[θ]*z0 + Cos[ϕ0 - ϕ]*Sin[θ]*Sqrt[1 - z0^2])^M};
sol1 = NDSolveValue[pde, Q, {t, 0, tmax}, {ϕ, 0, 2*Pi}, {θ, 0, Pi}];
```

The solution can be displayed in a number of ways.  For instance,

```
Manipulate[Plot3D[sol1[t, ϕ, θ], {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}, {θ, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesLabel -> {ϕ, θ, Q}, AxesStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, FontSize -> 16]], 
  {t, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, ContinuousAction -> False]
```

A sample plot, for `t = 10`, is

[image: t = 10]

---

Kuba: couldn't resist :)

First, solved till `t=40`.

```
Manipulate[
 SphericalPlot3D[ 1 + sol1[t, ϕ, θ], {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi},
   ImageSize -> 500, PlotRange -> 2, BoxRatios -> 1, 
  ColorFunction -> (Blend["TemperatureMap", #6] &)], {t, 0, 20, .1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, ContinuousAction -> False]
```

[image]

**Update**

As noted by the OP in his addition to the Question, the numerical solution presented above agrees only qualitatively with his analytical solution.  The accuracy of the numerical solution can be improved by reducing `MaxStepSize` and making the usual transformation, ` x = Cos[θ].  The revised equations

```
pde1 = {D[Q[t, ϕ, x], t] + D[x Q[t, ϕ, x] + (1 - x^2) D[Q[t, ϕ, x], x]/M, ϕ] == 0,
   Q[t, 0, x] == Q[t, 2*Pi, x], Q[t, ϕ, 1] == ((1 + z0)/2)^M ,
   Q[0, ϕ, x] == ((1 + x*z0 + Cos[ϕ0 - ϕ]*Sqrt[1 - x^2]*Sqrt[1 - z0^2])/2)^M};
sol1 = NDSolveValue[pde1, Q, {t, 0, tmax}, {ϕ, 0, 2*Pi}, {x, -1, 1}, 
   MaxStepSize -> {.005, .12, .054}]
```

now yield for `t = 10` the plot

[image: revised t=10]

which agrees well with the analytical result.  In fact, numerical and analytical results agree (at least for `M = 50`) up to about `t = 15`, above which they drift apart.  Thus, at `t = 20` the numerical result is

[image: t=20]

whereas the corresponding analytical result consists of eight identical, uniformly spaced solitons.

The numerical results are most sensitive to `MaxStepSize` for `x`.  Unfortunately, reducing it below `0.054` triggers a numerical instability.  I have tried numerous options for `Method` without improving the outcome.  Of course, there may be other options that I have not tried that may produce superior results.  Note, though, that I have found no sample problem in the voluminous `NDSolve` [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveOverview.html) that includes a term of the form `D[Q[t, ϕ, x], x, ϕ]`, which appears to make this problem distinctive.

Comment: @Kuba, What a great addition.  Thanks.

Comment: brilliant animation @Kuba! :)

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this numerical solution does not overlap with analytical form of the expression I have derived - it resembles it, but time scales and behaviour is different. I tried to increase WorkingPrecision, but an error appeared: "The precision of the differential equation (...) is less than WorkingPrecision (5.)."

Comment: What is you analytic solution?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Yes, it is important because I wanted to compare full differential equation (in the question) and without the second term (second order derivative). Moreover, in general I will have a much more complicated nonlinear partial differential equations and any analytical solution can not be derived. This is how I wanted to proceed, solve numerically full differential equations. Comparison between full equation and without the second order derivatives is connected with the classical-quantum correspondence in phase space, but I can see that simulations in Mathematica are not so straightforward...

Comment: If it doesn't work for simple example it won't for any other. I think I will have to write numerical scheme by myself, but I don't know how to handle this kind of differential equations. Maybe Math site will give me a hint

Comment: After more thought, I believe that disparities at small M may be due to a numerical instability, which should be easy to fix.  The disparities at large M more likely are due to spatial truncation errors.  I am traveling today but can take a harder look tomorrow, if you wish.

Comment: I am not familiar with numerical methods for partial differential equations (I will have to read many papers), so If You were so kind and take a look at this :) Thank You!

Comment: I have not forgotten about this problem but have not yet been able to eliminate the numerical instability at small `M`.  You mentioned more complex differential equations that you need to solve.  This one is solvable in large part because it is [separable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_partial_differential_equation).  Are your more general equations separable, even partially?

Comment: You can check this [Trimborn](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0802.1139.pdf) - eq. (45)

Comment: I have improved the accuracy of the numerical solutions significantly in the update to may Answer.  Unfortunately, I am out of ideas for now, so it is unlikely that I can improve on this.  I did look at the equation you mentioned in your last comment.  Probably, the transformation I used here, or something similar to it, can be applied to the more complex equation, if you wish.